# Getting error 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered, however i was loading files earlier

Tags: .net, 64-bit, oledb

I am getting an error `The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.` However, I have loaded many files using same service two days earlier. Why this issue has started occuring.

My machine is 64 bit window 7 OS. Every project in .NET solution is configured for ANY CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties of your project try targeting `x86` instead of `AnyCPU`:

[image]

Alternatively if you want to target AnyCPU you need to install the x64 bit Access OLEDB provider. You can [`download it from here`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255).

Comment: Do I need to use some other connection string in for 64 bit machine.

Comment: No, the connection string is the same.

Comment: I installed this as well, but that didn't work for me. Currently I am setting build type to x86, then only this code is working for me.